# Android GridView Runtime exception

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-glide, runtimeexception

I am trying to display GET response into the card view in android studio.
I am able to display the normal textual JSON (response) data on the XML layout. But when I try to use Glide to load the image from API and made a few changes to code then it's showing me some Emulator error.

**My code:**

```
package demo.com;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class DashboardUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "DashboardUser";
    GridView gridview;


    public TextView categoryList;
    InterfaceAPI APIinterface;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard_user);
        gridview = findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

        APIinterface = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitClientInstance().create(InterfaceAPI.class);

        //background thread
        //network call
        Call<List<category>> call = APIinterface.getCategory();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<category>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<category>> call, Response<List<category>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(response.body(), DashboardUser.this);
                    gridview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
                     }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<category>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"An error occured"+t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });


    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public List<category> catList;
        public Context context;

        public CustomAdapter(List<category> catList, Context context) {
            this.catList = catList;
            this.context = context;
        }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return catList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_dashboard_user,null);

        //find view
        TextView name=v.findViewById(R.id.txtDoctor);
        ImageView img=v.findViewById(R.id.imgDoctor);

        //set data
            name.setText(catList.get(i).getCatName());
            //set image
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(catList.get(i).getCatUrl())
                .into(img);

        return v;
    }

    }
```

Build is successful. But when I try to run the project with Nexus5 it gives below error:

```
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xea2d2bb0, tid 5890
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xea0e26e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea0e26e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xea42dd10) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xea2d2070, tid 5890
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fd968000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: demo.com, PID: 5808
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{demo.com/demo.com.DashboardUser}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridView
        at demo.com.DashboardUser.onCreate(DashboardUser.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5808 SIG: 9
---------------------------
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: SDKCtl multi-touch: Invalid packet signature 50545448 for packet type 808465440, size 825110831

10:57 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: SDKCtl multi-touch: Invalid packet signature 50545448 for packet type 808465440, size 825110831

10:57 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: SDKCtl multi-touch: Invalid packet signature 50545448 for packet type 808465440, size 825110831

10:57 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: SDKCtl multi-touch: Invalid packet signature 50545448 for packet type 808465440, size 825110831
```

Comment: i think you're using id of your Grid Layout (R.id.mainGrid ) as GridView.

Answer (score 1):

Your are trying to cast `android.widget.GridLayout` to `android.widget.GridView`.

Use `GridLayout` instead of `GridView`.